# mongooseim 6.0.0 cluster setup in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: azure, erlang, xmpp, mongoose-im

We are trying to create cluster of two mongooseim instances on Azure in same virtual network.  All necessary ports are opened in Azure security group.

How to change node name of two vms and join cluster of mongooseim?

I have tried to change in vm.args file but not working.

```
cat /etc/mongooseim/vm.args 
## Name of the node:
##   -sname node@host
## or
##   -name node@fully.qualified.domain.name
#$
## Without @something suffix `mongooseimctl debug` uses:
##   - NODE@`hostname -s` if -sname
##   - NODE@`hostname -f` if -name
## to attach a remote shell.
-sname mongooseim@localhost

## Cookie for distributed erlang
-setcookie ejabberd

## Heartbeat management; auto-restarts VM if it dies or becomes unresponsive
## (Disabled by default..use with caution!)
##-heart

+P 10000000 -env ERL_MAX_PORTS 250000

## Tweak GC to run more often
-env ERL_FULLSWEEP_AFTER 2
```